# How to find the type of a DB2 object

Tags: db2

I'm trying to revoke privileges of a user and to do so I have to know the types of DB objects. For example revoke command for a table would we different of a sequence.

When I ran the following query, some objects were returned with arbitrary object names. I have given one such result below

SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES WHERE AUTHID = SESSION_USER AND AUTHIDTYPE = 'U'

```
AUTHID    AUTHIDTYPE PRIVILEGE   GRANTABLE OBJECTNAME
DB2USER   U          CONTROL     N         SQL140423185953800
```

How can I find the object type (e.g. table, sequence, etc) of SQL140423185953800?

Comment: It's strange that you did not find the `OBJECTTYPE` column in the `SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES` view.

Comment: @mustaccio Wow. I have missed  that! That column had been printed outside the visible area of the window :S Didn't notice I have to scroll. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I have created a stored procedure that tries to solve this problem. You just need to execute the code to create the procedure, and then call it with the right parameters. The code is hosted here: https://gist.github.com/angoca/7434525

It does a select in multiple tables, looking for the object you are passing as parameter.

Comment: I tried your SP but it didn't return a result for those object names. Thanks anyway :) There are some ATOMIC statements run on the database at the table creation time, can they be the reason for these arbitrary object names?

Comment: Yes, sometimes they persist and you have to disconnect and reconnect, and they will disappear.